# Can I have a method called print (or such) in my class?

Tags: python, class, methods, printing, naming

When using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (community edition) on my Windows 7, I can have a class like so:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def print(self):
        print('x:', x)
```

And use it normally:

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x.print()
0
```

This code runs with no problems.
However, when I run the same code on my Ubuntu using gedit and terminal (`python x_file.py`), I get an error:

```
$ python main.py
  File "main.py", line 6
    def print(self):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why the difference, am I allowed to have a method called `print` in a class, or is this just one of PyCharm's features?

Comment: Can you post the code from both OS here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 there is absolutely no problem, however in python2 there was a [`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt) *statement* which precludes you from using it as an identifier, including a method name.

It seems like you have python2 on Ubuntu and python3 on Windows, hence the difference.

If you want to avoid the `print` statement in python2 add:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

At the top of your file and you should obtain python3's `print` function, thus allowing you to define a method called `print`, (see [this](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print) documentation).

---

Also note that without the `__future__` import and in python3 this line:

```
print('x:', x)
```

Outputs:

```
x: <value for x>
```

However in python2 *without* the special import you get:

```
('x:', <value for x>)
```

Because the `(...)` does not specify the arguments to the function but is interpreted as a tuple to be printed by the statement.

Comment: Ahh silly me, didn't realize our school computers (ubuntu) had old version of Python, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

By any chance your ubuntu python version is below 3 ? since Python 2 uses:

```
print "test"
```

and Python 3 uses:

```
print("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 2+ `print` is a special statement like `break`, `return`, `raise` and so on. You cannot override these by creating objects with the same name. In python 3+ `print` is a function and the argument is the string between parentheses. Builtin functions can be overridden in python so that's why you can define your own `print` (even outside your class) in python 3.
In your particular example PyCharm is probably based on python 3 and on your ubuntu machine you have '2.something'.

Off-topic: overriding builtins is usually not a good idea.